# Rendering local JSON data in vuepress

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuepress

I have a simple vuepress website, and I'm reading a `.json` file on the `index.md` using;

`{{ require('./nba.json') }}`

It works fine and looks like the image attached;

[json on vuepress site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI79O.png)

As you can see it doesn't look the best. In vuepress how can I specifically style what is being read from json, ie. change the font size, display the info in a neat way etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vuepress (and Vue + Webpack in general) imported `json` files are just JavaScript objects so you can use it with Vue to generate anything you want...

```html
<div v-for="i in items">
    <h2>{{i.Home_neutral}} - {{i.Visitor_Neutral}}</h2>
    <p>{{ i.Date }}</p>
</div>

<script>
import data from './nba.json'
export default {
  data () {
      return {
          items: data
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

There are two ways how to use this code.

1. You can put it into `docs/.vuepress/components` directory as `NbaMatches.vue` - it becomes [global component](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/using-vue.html#using-components) and can be used inside any `md` file as `<NbaMatches />` (you will need to wrap the template part - everything above `<script>` - into `<template></template>`)
2. You can just copy/paste above code into any `md` file directly as is and it should work

Comment: So this is essentially a component which I can call on in my `index.md`? How do I do this? `<nba_matches :items></nba_matches>`?